# how to see where and what the changes are when file is modified externally

Tags: emeditor

i modify file externally (see below), i want to know where and what the changes are in emEditor,
how to do ?
thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you positive that a file was changed externally? If not, this might be a false alarm. Which version of EmEditor are you using? If you are using an old version, please update to the latest version. Are you opening a network file?

Comment: yes,the file was changed externally,its local file, can i see the changes in emEditor when a  file was changed externally?  if can, i do not need to open "beyond compare" ,that will be convenient

Comment: OK. No, you can't see the changes unless you have a backup file of the original.

Comment: ok,thank you all the same!

Comment: I've just remembered there is a macro developed by our user. I've answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ActiveCompare](https://github.com/Emurasoft/library/blob/main/macros/ActiveCompare.jsee) macro, written by *Takahiro Kawakami*.

When the *File changed by another program. Reload with changes?* message box appears, select **Don't Reload**, and run this macro. You will be able to compare the current document with the file on disk.

Comment: WHEN this link gets broken yet again this answer will then again become of little value to others.

Comment: This is not my code, and I don't have the right to copy the code.